# How do I mute players in online multiplayer mode in Soul Calibur 4 for PS3?

Tags: ps3, soul-calibur-4

It is so annoying to hear other people talking and all their stupid friends you can hear in the background, when I'm trying to play Soul Calibur 4. I tried to find an option to mute players, but I could not find it. I also tried Google but came up empty handed.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to mute the other players. To work around this, I turn on my Bluetooth headset and leave it next to me instead of wearing it.